# Data from firebase not populating in my table view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

So I recently asked a question regarding firebase - but have refactored my code quite a bit as I wanted all of my firebase methods to be done in the same place. I am having the following issue after the refactor...

Data from my firebase database is not populating my tableview. I'm not too sure why this would be, as it was working fine before I moved the method to a separate file from my table view(for cleaner code). All I did was move the method that populates the array to a separate file, return an array and then reload the tableview after calling the method. Below is the code in question:

***In my FireBaseMethods class***

```swift
//-------------- POPULATE TABLE ARRAY -----------------//
    public func populateConsumableTableArray() -> [Consumable]{
        var tableArray = [Consumable]()

        //let the object populate itself.
        ref.child("Consumables").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            let dataChange = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]
            let aRequest = Consumable(aDict: dataChange!)
            tableArray.append(aRequest)
        })
        return tableArray
    }
```

***In my ListOfConsumablesViewController table view class***

```swift
class ListOfConsumablesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    private var methods:MethodsForController = MethodsForController()
    private var fireBaseMethods:FireBaseMethods = FireBaseMethods()

    private var consumableArray = [Consumable]()

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBOutlet weak var consumableTable: UITableView!

    //-------------------- VIEW DID LOAD -----------------------//
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Trying to populate the table view here...
        consumableArray = fireBaseMethods.populateConsumableTableArray()
        consumableTable.reloadData()

        self.consumableTable.dataSource = self
        self.consumableTable.delegate = self
    }

...

    //---------------------- FUNCTIONS FOR TABLE VIEW CELLS & TABLE ----------------------//
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(consumableArray.count)
        return consumableArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "consumableCell", for: indexPath) as! ConsumablesCell

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.adapterType.text = consumableArray[indexPath.row].getType()
        cell.count.text = String(consumableArray[indexPath.row].getCount())

        if Int(consumableArray[indexPath.row].getCount()) ?? 0 <= 0{
            cell.count.textColor = UIColor.red
        }else{
            cell.count.textColor = UIColor.black
        }

        cell.sku.text = consumableArray[indexPath.row].getSku()

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90
    }
}
```

As shown below, nothing populates in the table view... I'm assuming it's something to do with the method being in a separate file, but I'm not really sure why that would be?
[image]

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single, specific question per post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding the first issue: `observe` works asynchronously, `populateConsumableTableArray` will always return an empty array because the closure is executed much later. You need a completion handler. And it's pointless anyway to reload the table view **before** setting `dataSource` and `delegate`.

Comment: I suppose I am confused about how to set up a completion handler then...

So my method should look like this? 

public func populateConsumableTableArray(completionHandler: @escaping ([Consumable]) -> Void)

But then how do I call this method & set my array to it if it's void returning? Or should it not return void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple implementation of a completion handler

```
//-------------- POPULATE TABLE ARRAY -----------------//
public func populateConsumableTableArray(completion: @escaping (Consumable) -> Void) {

    //let the object populate itself.
    ref.child("Consumables").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        guard let dataChange = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }
        let aRequest = Consumable(aDict: dataChange)
        completion(aRequest)
    })
}
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.consumableTable.dataSource = self
    self.consumableTable.delegate = self

    //Trying to populate the table view here...
    fireBaseMethods.populateConsumableTableArray { [unowned self] consumable in 
       self.tableArray.append(consumable)
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.consumableTable.reloadData()
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Sorry, I'm very very new to firebase. I really do appreciate the help though!

Comment: The issue is not particularly related to Firebase. Almost all database and network requests work asynchronously.